# Linq: scoped DataContext, unit-of-work, repository

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext

I have been researching about the unit-of-work and the repository pattern in C#.  AFAIK, DataContext implements the unit of work pattern, and can be used to implement a repository interface.  One last piece that's lacking in DataContext is a way to share this resource globally within a predefined scope.

I briefly looked at NCommon as a solution to this missing piece.  Would you share your experience in NCommon, or recommend other solutions? Please also correct me if I have misunderstood.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always worked with DataContext in the same way NHibernate does: Having a static way to get it and different storages for storing it. For instance, it could be stored in the HttpContext.Current.Items collection for a web based application, or in Call.Context for the unit tests. When do you create the instance and when do you close it will depend on the scenario. Again, for web it make sense to do it on the Request_begin and Request_end events of your application. For unit tests, maybe on the setup and teardown.

Hope it helps.

*Edit: Here's some implementation*

```
public abstract class DataContextProvider
{
    public abstract DataContext GetCurrent();
    public abstract void OpenNew();

    public void CloseCurrent()
    {
        var current = GetCurrent();
        current.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In your data context you add this:

```
public static DataContextProvider Provider { private get; set; }

public static DataContext Current { get { return Provider.GetCurrent(); } }
```

*For web:*

In your web project you put this class:

```
public class WebDataContextProvider : DataContextProvider 
{
    private const string Key = "WebDataContextProvider.DataContext";

    public override DataContext GetCurrent()
    {
        return (DataContext)HttpContext.Current.Items[Key];
    }

    public override void OpenNew()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[Key] = new DataContext();
    }
}
```

And in your global.asax:

You add a field of type WebDataContextProvider:

```
WebDataContextProvider dataContextProvider = new WebDataContextProvider();
```

You override the application start event for doing:

```
DataContext.Provider = dataContextProvider;
```

In your Request Begin event you put:

```
dataContextProvider.OpenNew();
```

And in your Request End event you put:

```
dataContextProvider.CloseCurrent();
```

*For test*

For your test projects you can follow the same logic, but creating a TestDataContextProvider, like:

```
public class WebDataContextProvider : DataContextProvider 
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static DataContext Current;

    public override DataContext GetCurrent()
    {
        return Current;
    }

    public override void OpenNew()
    {
        Current = new DataContext();
    }
}
```

And in your open and close the data context in your SetUp and TearDown methods, and configuring the "current provider" in the constructor of the Test or the TestFixtureSetUp

Hope it helps.

Comment: What happens when you need to share this DataContext among objects for a specific task?

Comment: You use a sort of inversion of control. You can use a framework or put the DataContext as a parameter of the constructor of the class containing the task. O you can access it "staticly", like DataContext.Current (returning it from the defined context)

Comment: Who maintains DataContext.Current?

Comment: It depends. On web, it usually will go in a httpmodule or in the global.asax, setting it in each request using Request_Begin and Request_End events. In tests, it could be created in the SetUp and disposed in the TearDown.

Comment: I need a library that manages DataContext.Current.  For example, a function can specify whether it needs a new DataContext or inherits the current one from the caller.  The manager then manages the stack of DataContext created along the execution path.

Comment: It's really easy to implement, really.